# Inner Join between 2 sql having ROW_Number SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, row-number

I have gone through the particular posts but couldn't still fix the issue I having with Inner Join of two SQL statements with a `Row_number` function call in them.

Trying to pull data from two tables. I am using `Row_Number` to get the distinct policies as there are lots of duplicate values. I can't figure out what is wrong in the Inner Join part.

```
Select * 
from 
    (Select Distinct
         PolicyReference as IRIS_Policy_Ref ,
         REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Ch.ClaimSuffix,3,4),'-','') as Claims_Seq,
         CH.AccidentDate as Loss_Date,
         CH.AccidentYear as Loss_Year,
         CH.ClaimCreatedDate as Claim_Advised_Date,
         CH.NoticeDescription as Loss_Description,
         NULL as Conv_Claim_No,
         NULL as CHI,     
         NULL as Manual, 
         BrokerRef as Broker_Code,                
         Null as Current_ACR,
         Null as Current_IBNR,
         Source ='DCT',
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyReference ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) RowNum 
     from 
         dbo.Policy) PM 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Claims CH ON Ch.PolicyReference = PM.PolicyReference
where 
    PM.RowNum = 1
```

Error message sample -

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "Ch.ClaimSuffix" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   The multi-part identifier "Ch.AccidentDate" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   The multi-part identifier "CH.AccidentYear" could not be bound.

What am I doing wrong? It is not recognizing the claims table columns.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated. I am stuck in this since morning.

Thanks !!

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference Claims in your subquery like that because it hasn't been introduced. Why not move that join to the primary query like this?

```
Select * 
from 
(
    Select 
        PolicyReference as IRIS_Policy_Ref ,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Ch.ClaimSuffix,3,4),'-','') as Claims_Seq,
        CH.AccidentDate as Loss_Date,
        CH.AccidentYear as Loss_Year,
        CH.ClaimCreatedDate as Claim_Advised_Date,
        CH.NoticeDescription as Loss_Description,
        NULL  as Conv_Claim_No,
        NULL as CHI,     
        NULL as Manual, 
        BrokerRef as Broker_Code,                
        Null as Current_ACR,
        Null as Current_IBNR,
        Source ='DCT',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyReference ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) RowNum 
    from dbo.Policy P
    INNER JOIN dbo.Claims CH ON Ch.PolicyReference = P.PolicyReference
) PM 
where PM.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Many people like to use CTEs:

```
with table_with_rowsnums as (
Select * from (Select Distinct
PolicyReference as IRIS_Policy_Ref ,
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Ch.ClaimSuffix,3,4),'-','') as Claims_Seq,
CH.AccidentDate as Loss_Date,
CH.AccidentYear as Loss_Year,
CH.ClaimCreatedDate as Claim_Advised_Date,
CH.NoticeDescription as Loss_Description,
NULL  as Conv_Claim_No,
NULL as CHI,     
NULL as Manual, 
BrokerRef as Broker_Code,                
Null as Current_ACR,
Null as Current_IBNR,
Source ='DCT',
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyReference ORDER BY TransactionDate 
DESC) RowNum 
from dbo.Policy ) PM 
INNER JOIN dbo.Claims CH ON Ch.PolicyReference = PM.PolicyReference)
select * from  table_with_rowsnums where rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `select distinct` with `row_number()`.  In addition, `CH` has no reference.  You need to do the `JOIN` in the subquery:

```
select * 
from (Select pm.PolicyReference as IRIS_Policy_Ref ,
             REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Ch.ClaimSuffix, 3, 4), '-', '') as Claims_Seq,
             CH.AccidentDate as Loss_Date,
             CH.AccidentYear as Loss_Year,
             CH.ClaimCreatedDate as Claim_Advised_Date,
             CH.NoticeDescription as Loss_Description,
             NULL as Conv_Claim_No,
             NULL as CHI,     
             NULL as Manual, 
             BrokerRef as Broker_Code,                
             Null as Current_ACR,
             Null as Current_IBNR,
             Source ='DCT',
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pm.PolicyReference ORDER BY pm.TransactionDate DESC) RowNum 
         from dbo.Policy p JOIN
              dbo.Claims CH
              ON Ch.PolicyReference = PM.PolicyReference
        ) PM 
where PM.RowNum = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thank You all for your valuable comments. I will keep a consistent formatting while posting next time.

Comment: @guest678 . . . You should pay attention to what I say about `select distinct` as well.